# Finding success rate of patients visit based on table in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

thanks in advance for helping!
I have a clinic data with variables patient ID, Date of appointment and Physician ID. I want to find out the cases where a specific patient came back for follow up appointment within a week for his/her appointment. Not all patients came back, but there are some repeat cases.
I want to write a SQL query for it in access, but really struggling with this.

Comment: Show us the extent of your efforts to date by posting the SQL you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL would be like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Appointment A
INNER JOIN Appointment B
   ON A.Provider_ID  = B.Provider_ID 
      AND A.Patient_ID= B.Patient_ID 
      AND DateDiff("d", A.Appointment_Date, B.Appointment_Date) <= 7
```

Comment: Thanks, Sir. But, I just have one table called Appointment and these 3 fields are inside that table. Patient_ID is one field, Appointment_Date is second field and Provider_ID third field. In that case, what will be your code?

Comment: The code will be the same, @Pahari, Nizam is just referencing your one table twice. He calls the first reference to the Appointment table "A" and the second reference "B". This allows him to compare different appointment records. Specifically the interval between two (in days) where there is a match on patient and a match on provider.

Comment: Thanks Zec! There are 6 variables in the table including appointment date and patient id. I tried the following code after your comment, but it still doesnt work. What am I doing wrong here?          SELECT *
FROM Appointment
INNER JOIN Appointment
   ON 
APPOINTMENT.Patient_ID = APPOINTMENT.Patient_ID 
      AND DateDiff("d", APPOINTMENT.Appointment_Date, APPOINTMENT.Appointment_Date) <= 7;

Comment: You need to use different name for each of your reference. In the answer I haver used A and B as aliases.

Comment: You need to distinguish each reference.